# R Visualize cca plot in ggplot - Wrong arrows length

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I am trying to customize a CCA plot performed in Vegan R package. I have used a benthic cover matrix (%) vs a fish abundance matrix (number of individuals) to run this analysis. I have collected data in 4 coral reefs in 2 years. I want to have the sites dots in different colors (for reef sites) and shapes (years), fish species as text and the benthos as arrows. I have almost done it manually in ggplot, however the arrows length appear to be wrong. Comparing my plot with the "autoplot" and "plot.cca" generated plots, my arrows looks too short. My question is how can I solve this issue?

Please copy "benthos" and "fish" dataframes from this link: http://pedromeirelles.com.br/blog). The figures (ggvegan, cca.plot and ggplot)  can be find in this link too. I cannot publish images here yet and the dataframes are too big. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Thank you very much in advance.

Below the scripts I have used to draw the plots.

### ggplot manually draw

```
library("ggplot2")
library("vegan")
library("grid")
library("ggvegan")

benthos <- please copy this dataframe from the link above
fish <- please copy this dataframe from the link above
attach(fish)
fish.num<-fish[,3:ncol(fish)]
benthos.num <-benthos[,3:ncol(benthos)] 

mod <- cca(fish.num, benthos.num)

cca.res<-summary(mod)
cca.sites <-data.frame(cca.res$sites)
ord_df<-data.frame(Site=Site,Year=Year,CCA1=cca.sites$CCA1,CCA2=cca.sites$CCA2)
ord_df$Year <- factor(ord_df$Year)
ord_df$Site <- factor(ord_df$Site)
exp<-cca.res$concont
exp<-data.frame(exp$importance)
cca.species<-data.frame(cca.res$species)
cca.species<-data.frame(Cca1=cca.species$CCA1,Cca2=cca.species$CCA2,species=rownames(cca.species))
cca.benthos<-data.frame(cca.res$biplot)
cca.benthos<-data.frame(cca1=cca.benthos$CCA1,cca2=cca.benthos$CCA2, Species = rownames(cca.benthos))

ggplot(ord_df) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=CCA1, y=CCA2, color=Site, shape=Year),size = 4)+
  geom_text(data = cca.species, 
        aes(x = Cca1, y = Cca2, label = species),
        size = 3,alpha=0.4,colour = "darkred") +
  geom_segment(data = cca.benthos,
           aes(x = 0, xend = cca1, y = 0, yend = cca2),
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")), size=1, colour = "grey") +
  geom_text(data = cca.benthos, 
        aes(x = cca1*1.5, y = cca2*1.5, label = Species),
        size = 5) +
  labs(list(title = NULL, x = paste("CCA1 (",round(exp[2,1]*100,digits=2),"%)"), y = paste("CCA2 (",round(exp[2,2]*100,digits=2),"%)"))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "gray70") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "gray70") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#43CD80","#9400D3","steelblue3","#DEB887"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white", size=1))+
  theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill='white'))+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = "white"))+

  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=14))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=14))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=14,color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=14,color="black"))+
  theme(axis.line.x=element_blank())+
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank())+
  theme(
panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

### ggvegen autoplot

```
autoplot(mod)
```

### plot.cca

```
plot(mod, type="n")
text(mod, dis="bp")
points(mod, display="sites",pch=21, col="red", bg="yellow", cex=1.2)
text(mod, "species", col="blue", cex=0.8)
text(mod, display = "sites", cex=0.7, col="red")
```

### I could not find differences in data plot input

```
fdat <- fortify(mod)
fdat
cca.benthos
vegan::scores(mod, display = "bp")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the step where both `plot.cca()` and `autoplot.cca()` scale the arrows to fit the plot window. This is done in `plot.cca()`, and was in `autoplot.cca()` prior to **ggvegan** 0.0-3, via the utility function `ordiArrowMul()`.

As of version 2.3-0 of **vegan** this function is exported from **vegan**. But it uses information from base graphics to do the scaling. Hence from version 0.0-3 of **ggvegan** there is a [non-exported function `ggvegan:::arrowMul()`](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan/blob/master/R/utils.R#L9) which will do the same job as `ordiArrowMul()` but from the data not the current plot limits. (In a future version of this function I plan to allow you to set the limits of the plot if you change `xlim` and `ylim` in the base plot.)

You should be able to just do

```
mul <- ggvegan:::arrowMul(cca.res$biplot,
                          rbind(cca.sites, cca.species))
cca.benthos <- data.frame(cca.res$biplot * mul)
```

(Not tested and I'm about to head out for the day - post a comment if not working and I'll look in more detail later.)

Comment: Thank you so much, Prof. @GavinSimpson! I could do this for the benthic and fish data and the plot was greatly improved.